# How to allow external music/audio to continue in Corona SDK apps when they launch?

Tags: coronasdk

In Corona SDK how do you allow existing music/audio already playing in the background when your app (corona sdk based app) is launched and run?  In particular:

1. iTunes Music/Podcasts - ability to have background music/audio to keep playing when you launch your app (i.e. corona sdk built)
2. Other Apps (e.g. audible.com app for audiobooks) - ability to have audio from such an app continuing when you launch your app (i.e. corona sdk built)

I'm guessing (2) may not be possible, but at least how do you implement (1)?   I know there are apps out there (well I've seen IOS ones at least) which offer the ability for your background music to keep playing, but need to find out how to do this with Corona SDK?  or if it's not yet possible just to understand this

Note, my app was intending to just play short audio clips (e.g. menu button pushes) on top of the background music/audio.  That is wasn't planning to stream music in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, Corona allows background music to be played no matter if it's from iTunes or other apps.

However since build 2126, there was a regression bug that made external (background) music stops when the app launched.

And it is fixed in the recent Corona daily build, 2179.

Please take a look at this Corona forum post if you want to know the detailed development for this issue:http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/40837-allow-external-music/

I have tested it & verified that the background music continues when my app launches if I build with build 2179 or before build 2126.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/audio/index.html

you can check the about audio load, play, streaming, pause etc.

audio.loadSound() — loads an entire sound into memory. It should be used for shorter audio files that may be used repeatedly throughout the app.

audio.loadStream() — reads in small chunks of an audio file over the course of its duration. It should be used for longer audio tracks like background music. Note that streamed files may have a slightly higher latency cost and CPU cost than files loaded with audio.loadSound()

Go through the above link.

Comment: any understand and use these Hari - what I was asking about is do you allow existing music/audio already playing in the background when your app (corona sdk based app) is launched and run, noting your app itself does also use sound

Comment: What do you exactly mean?  -You want the music being played in the background to be paused while one opens/runs the app?

Comment: want the music/audio playing the background from the previous app to keep playing (just like it does for iTunes musics playing, or an audiobook playing in the Audible app, when you start playing Candy Crush) - but noting in your app starting up it will have sound effects of it's own (just like Candy crush does, and they got it to work)

Answer (score -1):

I found this post corona post very useful related to it and it has content to resolve your issue, Please check:

http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/sample-code-loop-background-music-synchronized-your-apps

Comment: I've this one - unfortunately that doesn't address what I'm trying to do